# WCF restful web services | send image

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have to send 2 images to my web services which will add them in a Word document.

For the moment, I send the images as `base64`.

When I send only 1 image, there is no problem but when I send 2 images (maximum I can send), chrome is crashing. ( "ow snap, ..." ).

It crashed when I tried to send 2 x 762 KB images.
When trying with 1KB images, it works.

Should I send bytes array instead of base 64 ? Or any other way ?

I have already changed my `web.config` to allow to send more data.

**WEB CONFIG**

```
<binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding" transferMode="StreamedRequest" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
```

**EDIT**

I tried to add this in the web config but still not working.

```
<security>
     <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
     </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Is Chrome crashing despite how small the pictures are?
Is the problem in the size or the number?

Comment: Sending 2 small images (each 1.08KB) is OK. It crashed when sending 2 x 762 KB image.

Comment: @Weedoze Add this to your web.config<binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        </binding>

Comment: I can't add "messageEncoding=Mtom", maybe because i'm using WebHttpBinding ? Btw still not working

Answer (score 0):

In config file you have to increased the size to upload large data as following:

```html
<webHttpBinding>
 <binding name="web" maxReceiveMessagesize="250000000" maxBufferSize="250000000" maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeOut="00:10:00">

 <readerQuotas maxDepth="250000000" maxStringContentLeangth="250000000" maxArraylength="250000000" maxBytesPerread="250000000"
 maxNameTableCharCount="250000000"/>
 <security mode="None" />
 </binding>
 </webHttpBinding>
```

Please do check that you have already used the binding configure in the endpoint as following:

```html
But it still can not help. Please try to check that you have already used the binding configure in the endpoint as following:
<endpoint address="http://"
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="web"
                contract="..." name="..." />
```

Comment: As said in the question, I have already change the web.config like you writed it.